# How to show a div after postback on a button click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

Here i have a div in which i am showing it during the mouse hover in the master page and after mouse hover three href links will appear in that div .After clicking that href link it is traversing to another page,postback happens and that div is getting hidden in the master page.I need to show that div after that click also.I have used updatepanel and tried it but still it is not working.here is my code

//Div part

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div runat="server" class="divSUBMenu" id="describe" style="width: 700px; height: 20px;
 font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" onclick="show(0)">
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

//Onhover part

```
 <a href="#" onmouseover="showit(0)">
 <img src="Images/Analyze_over.jpg" name="image1" width="84" height="22" border="0"
 id="image1" alt="" /></a>
```

//Javascript for mousehover(working fine)

```
var submenu = new Array();
    submenu[0] = '&nbsp;<font style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="ATrendAnalysis.aspx">Trend Analysis</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="AEventPerformance.aspx">Event Performance</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="ACannibalization.aspx">Cannibalization</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="AHaloEffect.aspx">Halo Effect</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="AVolumeDecomposition.aspx">Volume Decomposition</a></font></span>';
        var delay_hide = 500;
        var menuobj = document.getElementById ? document.getElementById("describe") : document.all ? document.all.describe : document.layers ? document.dep1.document.dep2 : "";

        function showit(which) {
                clear_delayhide();
            document.getElementById("describe").style.visibility = 'visible';
            thecontent = (which == -1) ? "" : submenu[which];
            if (document.getElementById || document.all) {
                menuobj.innerHTML = thecontent;
            }
            else if (document.layers) {
                menuobj.document.write(thecontent);
                menuobj.document.close();
            }
        }
```

and finally the part below is not working during the onclick but this alert is working

```
function show(which) {
alert("test");
document.getElementById("describe").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Any suggestion??

EDIT:
This is the href am clicking

```
<a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" href="ATrendAnalysis.aspx">Trend Analysis</a>
```

Comment: try `document.getElementById("describe").setAttribute("style", "display:block;");`  it may work.

Comment: i have tried that also still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `ClientScriptManager`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx

Example:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkDisplayCount.Checked)
    {
        String scriptText = "";
        scriptText += "function DisplayCharCount(){";
        scriptText += "   spanCounter.innerText = " + 
            " document.forms[0].TextBox1.value.length";
        scriptText += "}";
        ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
           "CounterScript", scriptText, true);
        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "DisplayCharCount()");
        LiteralControl spanLiteral = new 
            LiteralControl("<span id=\"spanCounter\"></span>");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(spanLiteral);
    }
}
```

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
this one?\

Comment: No..Let me send you a example

Answer (score 0):

Since the `div` is set to `runat=server`, you could control this on the server side - setting `describe.IsVisible = false` initially, and changing it to `describe.IsVisible = true` post-click.

If for whatever reason this *must* be done on the client, due to reliance on other scripts or something, then make sure you're looking for the control by using the correct identifier - it *could* be, depending on the version of ASP.NET you're using, that the control is prefixed with `ctl00_x`. In fact, even in newer versions of ASP.NET (above .NET 3.5), I think the `UpdatePanel` *might* explicitly alter the identifiers of its elements using a prefix so as to keep track of what it contains, don't quote me on that though. Check the rendered markup output on the page to check this.